# Using javascript routes in Play Framework 2

Tags: javascript, ajax, playframework-2.0

I'm attempting to make ajax calls using jsRoutes in play framework. It works fine for requests that does not take any parameters, but when I try to call a controller method which takes a Long as a param, it fails with no error message. Here's some code to explain it better.

Controller class Users.java:

```
public static Result addToShortList(long id) {
 return whatever
}
```

conf/routes

```
POST    /shortList/:userId  controllers.Users.addToShortList(userId: Long)
```

In Application.java controller file i return the jsRoutes like this:

```
public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
        controllers.routes.javascript.Application.frontpage(),
        ...
        controllers.routes.javascript.Users.addToShortList(),
        controllers.routes.javascript.Users.removeFromShortList()));
}
```

Now in my javascript I can use the jsRoutes by doing the following:

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Users.addToShortList(id).ajax({
            success : function(data) {

                alert(data);
            },
            error : function(err) {
                //code always ends up here, with the err giving no eerror message at all!
                alert(err);             
            }
        });
```

It seems that the this functionality of the play framework is poorly documented, or maybe I'm just blind not to find it anywhere...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, figured the problem out myself. The problem seemed to be that I used long(primitive) in the controller method. Why this is a problem I do not know.

Comment: This is an issue with Play that I've run into myself: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/756